# Python - Special Characters causing [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python script to recursively search a folder and process its contents. It fails because some subfiles and subfolders have a special character in their names: '' I've looked at this character in a hex editor and it shows up as byte 0x00. In Windows, when I try to use this character in a filename, it lets me and doesn't complain that it is invalid (it shows up as a '.' floating at mid-height)

I've written a small script and a dummy folder testDir to demonstrate the issue:

It causes the error: WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '../with_special_chars/testDir?/*.*'

```
import os

root_directory = r"../with_special_chars/"

def explore_folder(root_directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(root_directory):
        fullpath = os.path.join(root_directory, filename)
        print(fullpath)
        print(os.path.isdir(fullpath))
        print(os.path.exists(fullpath))

        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            print(fullpath)
        else:
            explore_folder(fullpath)

explore_folder(root_directory)
```

The output of the program before it prints the error is:

```
../with_special_chars/testDir?
False
False
```

It seems that Python is failing to read the directory because the special character is replaced with a '?' and then the resulting path is no longer recognized as a valid path. Is there a workaround for this? I would like to avoid having to change many file and directory names

Comment: Make sure you're using python 3.6 or later; older versions are hard to make work properly on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm at my work computer and am stuck with 2.7.10, I would have to argue with IT to get 3.6. I'll keep that in mind as a last resort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle undecodable filenames in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409381/how-to-handle-undecodable-filenames-in-python)

Comment: Yikes, 2.7.10 is pretty old, that sounds like a major security risk.